# Linkedin API get company posts

Tags: php, laravel, api, linkedin-api

I created an app associated with my company page (of which I am the admin and the creator).

[image: permissions]
I'd like to get the posts of this page in php.

I can easily get the access token with this function in laravel

```
public function authorization(Request $request)
{
    // Check if we already have a valid access token
    $authorized = Cache::get('access_token');

    if (!$authorized) {
        // We will continue with the authentication process
        $authorization_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization';

        $query_parts = array(
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'client_id' => config('linkedin.client_id'),
            'redirect_uri' => route('admin.linkedinNews.callback'),
            'state' => config('linkedin.state'),
            'scope' => 'w_member_social'
        );

        $query = http_build_query($query_parts);
        return redirect($authorization_url . '?' . $query);
    } else {
        // We can skip the authentication process
        return redirect(route('admin.linkedinNews.shares'));
    }
}
```

From what I see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api?tabs=http, I need to put the scope "**w_organization_social**" or "r_organization_social", but I can't find a way to do it.

If I use one of these scopes for authentication I get this error

```
 "Scope & quot; r_organization_social & quot; is not authorized for your application"
```

Whenever I try to make the call to *"/share"* with an access token with scope *w_member_social* I get this error

```
public function shares(Request $request)
{
    // Check if we already have a valid access token
    $authorized = Cache::get('access_token');

    if (!$authorized) {
        return redirect(route('admin.linkedinNews.auth'));
    } else {
        $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares';
        // https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners={URN}&sortBy=LAST_MODIFIED&sharesPerOwner=100
        $response = Http::asForm()->withToken($authorized)->get(
            $url,
            [
                'q' => 'owners',
                'owners' => 'urn:li:organization:MYCOMPANYID',
                'sortBy' => "LAST_MODIFIED",
                'sharesPerOwner' => "100",
            ]
        );

        dd($response->body());
    }
}


{" serviceErrorCode ": 100," message ":" Not enough permissions to access: GET / shares "," status ": 403}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong ... but what?

Maybe the entity company and organization are two different things?

Comment: That first function gets the _authorization code_, are you then using it to get an _access token_? I can’t quite tell. Regardless, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access?context=linkedin%2Fcontext), I think you need to request access to MDP.